# Searching Python Documentation

Tags: python-2.7

I am learning Python and I am struggling with finding good documentation for functions.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
randn = np.random.randn
s = Series(randn(5), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

For example I want to know more about the `random.randn` function in `numpy`.

I tried using the `help(Series)` function that is in `pandas` but it didn't pinpoint that specific function and how it is used.

What is the most efficient way to access this documentation within a Python IDE? Because the help() function isn't doing it well.

Comment: Google? I was feeling lucky: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html. `numpy` and `pandas` both have extensive documentation online, as does Python itself.

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for a way to do it in the Spyder IDE. Pull in that documetation using a help function of sorts

Comment: Perhaps you should consider mentioning that? Note that `help(np.random.randn)` will give you what is on that webpage.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Is that what you use when you want to learn more about a function? Are there any others that may help? Because I used help function on the Series function but with no success. Just spat out this long output with all these other functions that were not the Series function

Comment: No, I read the online documentation, but for `numpy` they're the same. Any other what? What exactly was your problem with `help(Series)` - what would you like instead? It's very difficult to suggest *"that specific function and how it is used"* with such a widely-used data structure.

Comment: Sorry Jon. I am just used to R, trying to switch to Python. In R if I am confused about a function, what it serves, the paramters it takes, I just "?", eg "?write.csv and the documentation is automatically pulled up for *Only* that specific function. With Python when I did a help on the Series function I got a giantic documentation list that included other functions that was not the "Series" function

Comment: Here is another one for example, I think the Series function is in Panda, but it doesn't say that in the help(Series) documentation. In R, it tells me exactly which library the function is derived from

Comment: `Series` **isn't a function**, it's a *class*. Those "other functions" will probably be the methods and attributes of that class, as shown here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html. If you use sensible namespaces (e.g. `import pandas as pd ... s = pd.Series(...)`) it should always be obvious where particular names have come from.

Comment: Ok. So I guess python users use the help() function for functions and classes. Sorry Jon just trying to find an easier way to pull up documentation in the IDE specifically for a class/function. Apologize for being nooby.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand your problem - `help(whatever)` **does** *"pull up documentation in the IDE specifically for a class/function"*, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Jon, please type help(Series) in a python IDE. and then compare it with the link you sent me. They are not the same documentation. The help function does not pull down the page.

Comment: I can't - I don't have `pandas` installed on this machine. Third-party libraries are responsible for defining their own `help` material - aside from contributing to improving the project, there's not much you can do.

Comment: OK, well I am just telling you they are not. I wish the documentation that was pulled down looked like the link you sent me. Having been on R for many years you get used to where things are located. I am still trying to learn where all previous functions I have used are stored within the different Python Modules. For example, I have to figure out if I want to pull in csv data which module does that, convert the data to a data.frame I have to find which module does that, convert the time/date to something python can recognize, regressions, etc. So it's a hassel.